# Why SVG is not rendered in NEXTJS project after deploying on vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, vercel

I had created a showcase single page nextJS application styled with Tailwind CSS. I am adding the background of a component `SectionWrapper` as an `svg` file.

I had created a custom class in `global.css` using `@layer` utility like this

```
@layer components {
  .banner {
    @apply bg-[url('../assets/banner.svg')] bg-no-repeat w-full bg-cover bg-center h-full;
  }

  .banner02 {
    @apply bg-[url('../assets/banner02.svg')] bg-no-repeat w-full bg-cover bg-center h-full;
  }
  .
  .
}
```

And using them in my `index.js` like this where I'm passing `banner` as props.

```
.
.
.
<Sectionwrapper
        title="Creative way to showcase the store"
        description="The app contains two screens. The first screen list all NFTs while the second shows the details of a specific NFT."
        mockupImg={assets.mockup.src}
        banner="banner02"
      />
.
.
.
```

And in `sectionWrapper` component, it is used as `${banner}` in the first div.

```
import React from "react";
import assets from "../assets";
import Button from "./Button";

const Sectionwrapper = ({
  title,
  description,
  showBtn,
  banner,
  mockupImg,
  reverse,
}) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={`min-h-screen flex justify-center items-center p-16 sm:p-8 ${banner} ${
        reverse ? "bg-white" : "bg-primary"
      }`}
    >
      <div
        className={`flex items-center w-11/12 sm:w-full minmd:w-3/4 ${
          reverse
            ? "flex-row-reverse md:flex-col-reverse fadeRightMini"
            : "flex-row md:flex-col fadeLeftMini"
        } `}
      >
        .
        .
        .
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sectionwrapper;
```

#### ISsue

The SVGs are working fine in the local environment. But on the deployed environment of `Vercel` and `Netlify` , the SVG is not rendering. It is working fine in localhost but not in production.

**in local env**

[image: local]

**on vercel/netlify**

[image: vercel]

#### More resources

Github link [here](https://github.com/mohitm15/NFT-MarketPlace-showcase)

Vercel link/Live Demo [here](https://nft-market-place-showcase.vercel.app/)

Comment: Checking the live deployment, we can see it is trying to fetch `webpack:///mini-css-extract-plugin/_next/static/media/banner02.f898f0c4.svg`, which is certainly not an accurate URL. It should be https://nft-market-place-showcase.vercel.app/_next/static/media/banner02.f898f0c4.svg, which works.
This can be a starting point.

Comment: Can you clarify what change I need to make?

Comment: I am unsure. But it can be a question of tweaking `next.config.js` or hunt down if a dependency is affecting that behavior.

Comment: Have you tried moving the SVGs folder to the `public` folder and changing their reference to `url('/assets/banner.svg')`?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the SVGs to the `public` folder and updating thier path in `tailwind.config.js` to this

```
@layer components {
  .banner {
    @apply bg-[url('/banner.svg')] bg-no-repeat w-full bg-cover bg-center h-full;
  }

  .banner02 {
    @apply bg-[url('/banner02.svg')] bg-no-repeat w-full bg-cover bg-center h-full;
  }
  .
  .
}
```

works for me.